# python : I want to avoid using 'copy' module

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, copy

(The code below is not a working code. It's just to convey ideas)
My intention is to recursively call sumsubset(arr.remove(el),num,org), parsing updated arr.
However, this will cause unwanted removal to original arr which will cause error. So, I often depend on copy module, feeling somewhat awkward.

Is there any better way parsing updated arr without using copy module?
Thanks for answering my first question.

```
arr=[1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 9, 9, 13, 13, 13, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 19, 19, 20]
num=36

import copy

def sumsubset(arr,num,org):

    for el in arr:
        if el==org:    return [el]

        tmp=copy.copy(arr)
        tmp.remove(el)
        result=[el]+sumsubset(tmp,num-el,org)

    return result

a=sumsubset(arr,36,36)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = arr[:]
```

or

```
tmp = list(arr)
```

Both would create a new object, not just copying the reference to the original `arr`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what i really wanted was parsing updated arr without creating another object